# EC2 Instance Cloning - Windows Server

Tags: windows, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

Is it possible to clone a EC2 instance data and everything existing but for Windows EC2 instance (not Linux)?

Does any license needs to be included/transferred?

Can same user (Admin) and password be used for the new instance?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is possible. First, you need to create an image from your current instance. This can be done in the instance console, just like the image below.

[image]

After that, go to the side menu, and under **Images** click on **AMIs** and wait for your newly created image to change it's status from pending to available. Now, go to the launch image menu, and on the sidebar, click on **My AMIs** and choose the image you just created. After that, just follow the normal process.

[image]